# Preferring const T&&

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

Are there any situations where you would prefer `void fun(const T&&)` over `void fun(T&&)` and `void fun(const T&)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some situations for preferring `const T&&` over `T&&`. For example, suppose you have a method that should only be called with a const lvalue reference, because the method stores the reference. In this case, it is good to add a *deleted* override for rvalue references, to avoid that a temporary object can be bound to a const lvalue reference.

```
void foo(const bar& b) { ... }
void foo(const bar&&) = delete;
```

If you have a method returning a `const bar`, the second overload will be chosen. It wouldn't work with `T&&` instead of `const T&&`.

```
const bar make_bar() { ... }
foo(make_bar()); // ERROR, foo is deleted.
```